# Applying a naming strategy to a class name when serializing a POJO with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

When using Jackson's WRAP_ROOT_VALUE serialization setting and serializing a POJO, the class name is used as the root value in the serialized JSON.

```
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

Question - how can I apply a naming strategy to the class name? I'd like to convert the class name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it is by using `@JsonRootName` annotation like:

```
@JsonRootName( value = "smsMessageRequest" )           
public class TextMessage {

    private String message;
    private String address;
}

public static String toJson(Object object) throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
}
```

Which yielded:

```
{
  "smsMessageRequest" : {
    "message" : "abc",
    "address" : "123"
  }
}
```